# Flutter firebase crashlytics Android error

Tags: android, flutter, firebase

I'm running into this error when I run the project on an Android device (iOS devices work perfectly ). Does anyone have encountered this error and fix it?

These are the Firebase plugins that I use:

```
firebase_core: ^2.15.1
  firebase_auth: ^4.7.2
  firebase_storage: ^11.1.0
  firebase_analytics: ^10.4.4
  firebase_crashlytics: ^3.3.5
```

And this is the error:

Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not find any version that matches com.google.firebase:firebase-sessions:[15.0.0, 16.0.0).
> Versions that do not match:
> - 1.0.2
> - 1.0.1
> - 1.0.0
> Required by:
> project :app > project :firebase_crashlytics > com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:18.4.0